# Phalcon 5 - Sending post request to controller results in empty post data

Tags: php, phalcon, php-8

I'm using a docker setup with php 8.0.15 + phalcon 5.0.0beta2 and i'm trying to do a simple post request using the fetch api to a route.

```
/* inside router.php */
$apiGroup = new Router\Group();
$apiGroup->setPrefix('/api');
$apiGroup->addPost('/user', 'UserApi::post');
```

```
/* somewhere in my controller action */
$data = [
'email' => $this->request->getPost('email', [ Filter::FILTER_EMAIL ]),
'password' => $this->request->getPost('password', [ Filter::FILTER_STRING ]),
];
```

```
/* in my js */
fetch(url, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
body: JSON.stringify(someData)
}).then(dostuff);
```

My problem is that `$this->request->getPost('email')` returns null and when debugging I saw that $_POST is also empty. Using `$this->request->getRawBody()` and `$this->request->getJsonRawBody()` do yield results since my data is actually there. I could very well just use `getJsonRawBody()`, but i'm wondering why the behaviour? (I used phalcon 3.* for another project and it worked just fine)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the get parameters as well? Just in case.

Comment: Get params seem ok. Let's say I run a post to ```/api/users?a=1&b=2``` the query params are fine, I can see them in ```$_GET``` and also using ```$this->request->get()```.

Comment: Is it possible that the params you search for as POST parameters could be GET parameters?

Comment: It's actually the ```Content-Type``` issue that @IMSoP pointed out below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for Phalcon's Request object](https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/request) explains that it is primarily a wrapper around PHP's native "superglobals", such as `$_POST`. In particular:

> The $_POST superglobal contains an associative array that contains the variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP `Content-Type` in the request. You can retrieve the data stored in the array by calling the `getPost()` method

Note that important caveat that this array is only populated when using two specific content types - specifically, the two content types that browsers use when submitting HTML forms. Form processing is the original task PHP was built for, and it can handle things like file uploads; but it doesn't natively do anything with JSON, XML, or other input types.

(As an aside, that documentation is subtly wrong: despite its name, `$_POST` will be populated for any HTTP method with an appropriate request body, e.g. `PUT`, just as `$_GET` is populated even when the method is `POST`.)

In your request, you're not using those content types, because you're posting a JSON string, so PHP doesn't populate `$_POST`, and Phalcon doesn't have anything to read with `getPost()`.

As you've discovered, there's a separate method which allows you to decode the JSON body to a PHP array:

> getJsonRawBody(): Gets decoded JSON HTTP raw request body

There's no mention of JSON at all in [the Phalcon 3.4 Request documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/request) so I'm not sure whether that functionality has changed, you've misremembered, or you were using some additional plugin or configuration.

The REST tutorial shows usage of `getJsonRawBody()` in both [the 5.0 version](https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/tutorial-rest) and [the 3.4 version](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/tutorial-rest).

Comment: Yep, that was the bugger. In my current phalcon 5.0 build i'm using my own fetch api wrapper  for ajax requests that by default uses ```"Content-Type": "application/json"```. If i change to the ones mentioned in the docs, it works as expected. 

In my old 3.4 project, i was using jquery ajax that did things under the hood so phalcon would play nice :)

Thanks for pointing out the content type paragraph in the phalcon docs and the other tips. :)